# RIP Update Packets

Tags: routing, rip

How Many Routes Can be carried by a RIP Version 1 & RIP Version 2 Update Packets ?

I Know Both RIP Version 1 & 2 Using the Metric of Hop Count and Maximum Hop Count is 16.

Comment: Thank you for your question.  Are you asking the maximum number of RIP routes a router can advertise, or the maximum number of routes that will fit in a RIPv1 / RIPv2 packet?

Comment: Hi Mike, I am Particularly Asking about Maximum Number of Routes that will fit in a RIPv1 / RIPv2 Packet ?

Comment: This is not hard to calculate, but may I ask why it matters?

Comment: RIP is Very Limited and I would like to know about the RIP Packet Size and Memory handled by it, How much Routes it can accommodate in an update packet.

Comment: I Found the Answer, Its 25 Routes can be carried by RIP Update Packet.   Reference : http://www.cisco.com/cpress/cc/td/cpress/fund/ith2nd/it2444.htm

Comment: please add this as an answer below and accept it in a couple of days... or you could just delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25 Routes can be carried by a RIP Update Packet.

Reference : [Cisco Press](http://www.cisco.com/cpress/cc/td/cpress/fund/ith2nd/it2444.htm)